# react native play sound on event

Tags: react-native

I have a component like:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'


class MovieList extends Component {


    handlePress() {
        // Play some sound here
    }

    render() {
        const { movie } = this.props
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}>
                <View style={styles.movie}>
                    <Text style={styles.name}>{movie.name}</Text>
                    <View style={styles.start}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Start</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

Here when I touch the `view` I want to play some sound. 
I have googled about it but not found any appropriate answer

Is there anyway I can play sound when I press to something? 
How can I do this ?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 23):

Check out [React Native Sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound) - a cross platform component for accessing device audio controls.

You can use it like so:

```js
const Sound = require('react-native-sound')

let hello = new Sound('hello.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})

hello.play((success) => {
  if (!success) {
    console.log('Sound did not play')
  }
})
```

Comment: Any example using this library `react-native-sound` but with url mp3 link?

Comment: You may want to require the sound also, else it is likely to error out. https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/120

Comment: How to play sound on button press ? can u show some example

Comment: whAT is "MAIN_BUNDLE". I copy paste the code just replace the name of my sound file but it is not playing ...

Comment: just a heads up there's a documented bug in this that more people than just myself are running into and can't resolve. there's an android flag check happening with RNSound and myself and others that are making an iOS-only app are having issues resolving.

Answer (score 8):

You can try Audio component from [expo-sdk](https://github.com/expo/expo-sdk).

Check an example [here](https://repl.it/J7i6/48).

It works with sdk 18.

Comment: link broken @niakrais

Comment: A lot has changed since 2017, other answers are probably more relevant now.
Anyways for historical purposes https://replit.com/@eryshev/Minimal-Sound-Example#index.js

Answer (score 2):

You can play the sound with the `expo-av` library like this.

```
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
class MovieList extends Component {


   async handlePress() {
     try {
        const { sound: soundObject, status } = await 
           Audio.Sound.createAsync('sound.mp3', { shouldPlay: true });
        await soundObject.playAsync();
        } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
    }

    render() {
        const { movie } = this.props
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}>
                <View style={styles.movie}>
                    <Text style={styles.name}>{movie.name}</Text>
                    <View style={styles.start}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Start</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```