# How to play audio in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-sound

I tried to use **react-native-video** to run audio from **uri** source, but when i run the audio nothing happens.

so what package should i use for Audio in **react-native**?

Comment: Try [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play sound in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737196/how-to-play-sound-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this [tutorial by medium](https://medium.com/applantic/getting-started-with-sound-audio-in-react-native-e1dc2fd50b78)