# React-Native-Sound path for ios file?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-sound

I'm curently developping an app on React-Native and I need to play sound.
The fact is that I am on Ubuntu and developing with IntelIJ Idea.

I'm using `react-native-sound` library to play sounds.

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737196/how-to-play-sound-in-react-native), I know where I put my .mp3 file for android, but the files have to be somewhere in the ios section as well ?

Where do we put them ?

Answer (score 3):

For iOS:

- Open Xcode and add your sound files to the project. (Right-click the project and select Add Files to [PROJECTNAME])

[See Documentation for React Native Sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound)

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]